How to fire OnTriggerEnter/Exit when enable/disable collider while 2 already overlaps in Unity
Basically what i'm trying to do is FTG games' hit/hurtbox, where the hitbox should appear short amount of time in a desired position.
Which when 2 player got close, P1 hitbox position should already be inside P2's hurtbox.
But as far as i know, Physics run before Update, there for when i enable collider component, only OnTriggerStay will run after this frame, and i have no idea how to implement it.
I have rigidbody on hurtbox.

in your on triggerenter/exit set a bool, so if item type 1 then yes - on exit no... same again for item type 2.. then you can test if item1 and 2 then do whatever

Try keeping a list of current collisions and updating it as you need
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CollisionList : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Declare and initialize a new List of GameObjects called currentCollisions.
    List<GameObject> currentCollisions = new List<GameObject>();

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {

        // Add the GameObject collided with to the list.
        currentCollisions.Add(col.gameObject);

        // Print the entire list to the console.
        foreach (GameObject gObject in currentCollisions)
        {
            print(gObject.name);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {

        // Remove the GameObject collided with from the list.
        currentCollisions.Remove(col.gameObject);

        // Print the entire list to the console.
        foreach (GameObject gObject in currentCollisions)
        {
            print(gObject.name);
        }
    }
}

Source: https://discussions.unity.com/t/getting-a-list-of-colliders-inside-a-trigger/95749/2
